# Give examples of the following rings (concerning identities)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Disclaimer**: I do not assume rings to be unital (otherwise the question wouldn't make sense).

> Give examples of a ring $R$ with subring $S$ such that
>
> (1) $R$ has an identity but $S$ has not.
>
> (2) $S$ has an identity but $R$ has not.

**Attempt**:

(1) Take $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = 2 \mathbb{Z} = (2)$

Suppose that $S$ has an identity $e$, then we must have (in $S$)

$$2e = 2$$

This is also true in $R$, and thus we can conclude $e = 1$. But $1 \notin S$. Contradiction. Thus $S$ has no idenity.

(2) Take $R$ the compactly supported functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is easily seen to be a subring of the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (and in fact thus also gives an example for (1), as this ring has  identity $f = 1$). Suppose $R$ has an identity $g$. Take a function $l$ that is non-zero everywhere. Then we must have

$$lg = l \implies l(g-1) = 0 \implies \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) = 1 \implies g = 1$$

But $g \notin R$. Thus $R$ has no identity.

Define a function $k$ as the indicatorfunction $k= I_{[0,1]}$ which is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. This function is compactly supported and an idempotent. Hence, the ideal $(k) = kR$ is a subring with identity $k$ (since $(kr)k = k^2r = kr$).

*Observation*: If $R$ has an identity that also lives in $S$, this is also the identity for $S$. Thus the only way $S$ can be non-unital when $R$ is unital is that the idenity of $R$ does not live in $S$.

Is this correct?

Comment: For $(2)$, matrix rings are nice, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656381/nontrivial-subring-with-identity-of-a-ring-without-identity).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought a while on this question and would also like to know if what I tried works as well. Thank you.

Comment: @user661541 Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both examples and the observation are correct.

Note for (2), that any *idempotent* element $e$ (even in a nonnecessarily commutative ring) gives rise to a subring with identity, namely $eRe$.

Answer (score -1):

I think these examples are sufficient.

1. R has an identity but S has not.
   R={0,1,2,3} under addition and multiplication modulo 4.
   S={0,2} under the same operations
2. S  has an identity but R has not.
   R={0,2,4,6,8,10} under addition and multiplication modulo 12.
   S={0,4,8} under the same operations.(S is even a field)

Comment: A field without 1. Interesting... Inverses don't make sense then...

Comment: 4 is the multiplicative identity; $4 \times 4= 4, 8 \times 4= 8$